# CakePHP admin index

Tags: php, mysql, oop, cakephp

I have an admin panel where I would like to filter users by groups..
Group 1 has 
  - User 1 
  - User 2 
  - User 3 

Group 2 has
 
  - User 6 
  - User 4 
  - User 9
How can I make a find method and fiter users by groups.

```
function admin_index() {

    // This function get al the users I want to filter by groups
    $this->set('users', $this->User->find('all'));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$this->Users->find('all',array('conditions'=>
                       array('Group.name IN'=>array('Group1','Group2','Group3'))
              )
);
```